# Problem trying to create columns multiple times, in google spreadsheets

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to update a spreadsheet using gspread. In the process,sometimes I need to add columns to the worksheet. But I realized that the method `add_cols` from gspread only works at the first time. At other times, it doesn't add the columns and doesn't raise any error. This piece of code is where I create more columns and it's called multiple times during the execution.

```
if 'exceeds grid limits' in error_msg:
    print("Insufficient number of columns to insert the result.")
    print('Creating 4 columns')
    try:
        sheet.add_cols(4)
```

The function `add_cols` only works again, when I open the spreadsheet again, using `open_by_key`.

Comment: in your except statement, try changing it to `except Exception as e: print(e)` and say what happens, unless if that's already there

Comment: It's already there. But it doesn't raise any error.